# Cassandra Phantom tutorial : Are there any basic tutorials for using Phantom?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I've looked around but couldn't find a single tutorial on getting started with Phantom. Although it is being actively developed by dedicated folks, I find it very surprising that there are no quickstart tutorials around. Please share links to any tutorials if one has come across

Comment: Hi @texens, have a look at the example module, it should be enough to get you off the ground. We are in the process of adding better tutorials for the upcoming release!

Comment: I wanted to use phantom to build a connector b/w apache spark and cassandra. I found spark-cassandra-connector by datastax, which fulfilled my requirement. Hence, I abandoned by plan of building a in-house connector b/w the spark and cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout the phantom-dsl examples in the source folder, but if not, I've uploaded an example to my github showing how to modeling cassandra tables in scala using phantom-dsl according to the documentation.

https://github.com/iamthiago/cassandra-phantom

Answer (score 1):

Docs location is confusing. They are in the .md files listed at the top of this website

https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/tree/develop/docs

Also have a look in 'basics', 'commercial' and 'querying' directories.